# Recent border-image-source SVG won't work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, border

In one of my websites, I used border-image-source to set a custom border. This was working fine for 6 months or so, but recently it doesn't work in Chrome anymore (you don't see the border anymore). It still works in Safari for example. This is my code: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeeNev

```
<div class="border-sketch">
   <p>This is a div</p>
</div>

.border-sketch {
    border-image-source: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'); 
    border-image-slice: 3 1 4 3;
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Has Chrome changed anything as to why it doesn't work anymore? Or am I overlooking something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `border-style` and will work (solid, double...)

```
    .border-sketch {
     border-width: 1px;
  border-style: double;
    border-image-source: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NC
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dfb606s4/1/